# Making a parabola curve with SFML VertexArray: left side not rendering correctly

Tags: c++, sfml

I am new to SFML and I'm trying to print a graph of x ^ n using `sf::VertexArray`.

The `render()` function takes 2 parameters: the window, and a `std::vector` called 'functions', which introduces parabolas, like {"x^2", "x^4" ...}:

```cpp
void render(RenderWindow& window, const std::vector<std::string>& functions)
{
    for (const auto& func : functions)
    { 
        //Rendering x^n;
        auto s = func;
        s[0] = s[1] = '0'; //Deleting "x^" from s
        size_t n;
        std::stringstream ss(s);
        ss >> n;

        VertexArray curve(PrimitiveType::LineStrip, 100);
        for (float x = 0.f; x < window.getSize().x; x += 0.5f)
        {
            curve.append(Vertex(Vector2f(20 * x + window.getSize().x / 2, -pow(x, n) * 10 + window.getSize().y / 2)));
        }
        window.draw(curve);
    }
}
```

And here is my `main()` function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> functions;
    std::cout << "Type a count of the functions:\n";
    size_t count;
    std::cin >> count;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << "Type functions through ENTER(x^n):\n";
    std::string str;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != count; i++)
    {        
        std::cout << "y" << i << " = ";
        std::getline(std::cin, str);
        functions.emplace_back(str);
    }

    RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1200, 800), "Graph!");   

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(Color::Black);
        render(window, functions);   //We render graphs as fast as we can
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I tried to render "x^2", I saw this:

[image: Just a half of parabola prints normally]

But why? How I can fix this?

Comment: For `x=0`, your vertex still has `window.getSize().x / 2` as X coordinate. If your `x` is already in window coordinates, you should *not* add the center again. The left half you're seeing is probably because the linestrip implicitly starts at (0,0), I don't know SFML well enough to tell.

Comment: @Botje, I have to print a parabola in the center of the window, so I have to add window.getSize().x / 2 to X coordinate. 
Or, maybe I just misunderstood you?

Comment: You have to make sure that (0,0) ends up in the center of your window, yes. But you are iterating over window coordinates already, so you should subtract half the window size, not add it. Alternatively, you need to not loop over window coordinates and then have x be negative, that works too.